# rails translation missing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have set flash message in my controller like this

```
flash[:error] = t 'auth.login.empty'
```

My en.yml file has

```
en:
  auth:
    login:
      success: "Successfully logged in"
      empty: "Empty field cannot accespted"
      error: "Username and password doesn't match"
```

All are two `space indent`

I am getting flash as `translation missing: en.auth.login.empty`

Whether i have to make some configuration changes.

Comment: have you tried restarting your server?

Comment: turn it off & on again :)

Comment: Another reason, why the key might be missing are **reserved words** in YAML. Keys like `yes`, `no`, `on` or `off` must be strings, so instead of `NO: "Norway"`, you must write `"NO": "Norway"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was actually indented with tabs for the success, empty and error keys. I have fixed this up now.

Please ensure that you are *really* using spaces. There's no other reason that I know of as to why this would break.

Comment: sorry i could not test it right now. I used tab with `tab size 2`. We should use space not the tab right?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this.

A key I was setting at the top of my file was being over-written later on in the file:

```
# This was showing up as missing
invite:
  intent_msg: "Test intent message."

# because waaaay farther down the file I had the following:

invite:
  button_text: "<i class='fi-mail'></i> Send Invite"
```

Even though the two translations are for different keys, the second one was killing off the first one.

So now I have this:

```
invite:
  intent_msg: "Test intent message."
  button_text: "<i class='fi-mail'></i> Send Invite"
```

And all is well again. 
Watch out for that one folks.